# No sound + unstable system after plugging in headphones

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones

I'm using *Kubuntu 20.04* on the [Alldocube KNote X Pro](https://www.alldocube.com/en/parm/knotexpro-parm).

Sound is working without any problems until I try to use the in-built headphone jack.

When I plug in some headphones, audio output stops. Neither in-built speakers nor headphones produce any sound. In addition, the system starts to behave unstable. Opened applications don't respond anymore and others won't open. I have to switch to virtual console and initiate a reboot for the system to work normal again.

When in virtual console, following message is displayed repeatedly every second(s):

```
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x01270500
```

**Note**: `cmd=0x...` varies.

If i plug in the headphones before booting the system, they work without problems. Even plugging out switches back to speakers as intended. After plugging in headphones again the problem occurs once more.

I don't need the 'auto switch function' of the headphone jack, if no other solution is possible. Manually disabling audio output of speakers in ALSA settings if I use headphones would be ok. The freezing problem however is a bit uncomfortable.

*--- Additional infos, if needed: [output of alsa-info](https://pastebin.com/icrZsHwB) ---*

Thanks for your help!

-- caldon724